# Run Python script with parameter as Windows Service

Tags: python, windows, service, windows-services

I created a Windows Service with python. It works well when I run it with debug mode, but when I start the service it doesn't work. This is the sample of my script:

```
def run(param):
    subprocess.Popen(["C:\\SER\\txt_write.pyw",param], shell=True)
#txt_write is a simple script: put the parameter into b.txt

def add_param():
    x="123456"
    run(x)

class PythonCornerExample(SMWinservice):
    _svc_name_ = "name"
    _svc_display_name_ = "name disp"
    _svc_description_ = "desc"

    def start(self):
        self.isrunning = True

    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    def main(self):
        i=0
        while self.isrunning:
            add_param()
            f= open("C:\\SER\\a.txt","a+")
            f.write("xyz")
            f.close()
            
            time.sleep(25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PythonCornerExample.parse_command_line()
```

So, when I run this script in debug mode it put "xyz" text into a.txt, and calls another python script, that put the parameter (123456) into b.txt. This is how I want it to works.

My problem is,  installed as Windows Service the a.txt works, but b.txt doesn't.

What is wrong with my script? Why is it OK in debug mode, and why is it wrong as Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change last 2 lines with bellow code:

```
import servicemanager, sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
  if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    servicemanager.Initialize()
    servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(PythonCornerExample)
    servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
else:
    PythonCornerExample.parse_command_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed by the service start are in the args parameter of the constructor method of your class.

```
class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):   

def __init__(self, **args**):
```

You want them in sys.argv, where you'd get them if the parameters were coming from a command line.

So I simply did this.

```
sys.argv = args
```

And now I'm parsing my service parameters as if it came from the command line.

:)